# Make OU's Add users to AD, make Groups and add users to groups PowerShell

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, active-directory, windows-server-2016

I'm trying to write a script, but it stops working after making all OU's. The OU's are all made perfectly only the users and groups don't get created which in turn doesn't add the users to the designated groups.

I tried figuring this out one on my own, but can't seem to find the flaw in the script.

```
# import required modules
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

# Set Password
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "W@chtw00rd" -AsPlainText -Force

#Set FilePath
$filepath = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Lijst met Medewerkers FitNu.csv"

# Import file into variable
$users = Import-Csv $filepath

# Loop through rows, set variables and make new users 
ForEach ($user in $users) {
    
    $fname = $user.'Voornaam'
    $surname = $user.'Achternaam'
    $jtitle = $user.'Functie'
    $officephone = $user.'Telefoon'
    $office = $user.'Locatie'
    $department = $user.'Afdeling'
    $OUpath = $user.'Organizational Unit'
    $title = $user.'Functie'
    $location = $user.'Locatie'

# Make OU's
    New-ADOrganizationalUnit -Name "Asgard" -Path "DC=Asgard,DC=com" -ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion $false
    New-ADOrganizationalUnit -Name "$location" -Path "OU=Asgard,DC=Asgard,DC=com" -ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion $false
    New-ADOrganizationalUnit -Name "$department" -Path "OU=$location,OU=Asgard,DC=Asgard,DC=com" -ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion $false
    New-ADOrganizationalUnit -Name "DomainLocal" -Path "OU=$location,OU=Asgard,DC=Asgard,DC=com" -ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion $false

# Make Users
    New-ADUser -Name "$fname" -GivenName "$fname" -UserPrincipalName "$fname $surname" -Surname "$surname" -Path "OU=$location,OU=$department,OU=Asgard,DC=Asgard,DC=com" -ProfilePath "\\Thor\UserProfiles\$fname" -Homedrive "D" -Homedirectory "\\Thor\UserData\$fname" -AccountPassword $password -OfficePhone "+31$officephone" -Office "$office" -Department "$department" -Title "$title" -PasswordNeverExpires $True -ChangePasswordAtLogon $False -Enabled $True

# Make Groups
    $globalgroup = "GG_"+"$department"+"_"+"$location[0]"
    New-ADGroup -Name $globalgroup -GroupCategory Security -GroupScope Global -Path "OU=$location,OU=$department,OU=Asgard,DC=Asgard,DC=com"

    $domaingroupr = "DL_"+"$department"+"_"+"$location[0]"+"_R"
    New-ADGroup -Name $domaingroupr -Groupcategory Security -GroupScope DomainLocal -Path "OU=$location,OU=DomainLocal,DC=Asgard,DC=com"

    $domaingrouprw = "DL_"+"$deparment"+"_"+"$location[0]"+"_RW"
    New-ADGroup -Name $domaingrouprw -Groupcategory Security -Groupscope DomainLocal -Path "OU=$location,OU=DomainLocal,DC=Asgard,DC=com"

# Add Users to group
    Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $globalgroup -Members $user

}
```

Comment: I know I should blank out the names, AD and passwords, but it's in a test environment so I don't mind.

Comment: so ... [1] do you get any errors? ///// [2] what happens if you run one of the group lines on its own?

Comment: I'm gonna try that when I get home. In case of the New-ADUser, I got and Identity Not Found error. Which kinda confuses me...

Comment: @JordivanDeerse - when you get that info, please add it to your Question so that folks can find it easily. the full text of any errors you get will also help since PoSh often includes useful info buried in there ... [*grin*]

Comment: Sorry for leaving the error code out. I found out it had to do with the order in which I specified the OU's for the new users. Check the comments below. Thanks for your help!

Comment: you are most welcome! glad that you got things working ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

`-UserPrincipalName "$fname $surname"`

The User Principal Name should be `username@domain` and therefor cannot contain spaces. Because it is invalid it says Identity not found. I do not see any username construction anywhere in the script, so that's your next step. Its likely that just the username can be set here though, just make sure it does not contain spaces. A period is acceptable, but best is username@domain.

*`-UserPrincipalName` specifies a user principal name (UPN) in the format `<user>@<DNS-domain-name>`. A UPN is a friendly name assigned by an administrator that is shorter than the LDAP distinguished name used by the system and easier to remember. The UPN is independent of the user object's distinguished name, so a user object can be moved or renamed without affecting the user logon name. When logging on using a UPN, users no longer have to choose a domain from a list on the logon dialog box.*
Source: [https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/.../new-aduser?view=windowsserver2019-ps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/new-aduser?view=windowsserver2019-ps)

Comment: What I find kinda "odd" is;

I ran this script earlier with just the New-ADUser as specified above and it worked perfectly. I was able to login to the account as well and the space didn't matter, it gave no error and worked perfect.

Only when I tried to add the groups and OU's in the script it started giving this output.

I will however make the changes and close if this works!

Thanks for the remark!

Comment: The error was I specified the OU's in the wrong order. $department should come before $location. It didn't have anything to do with the UserPrincipal name.

Answer (score 0):

The `Add-AdGroupMember` takes for its `-Member` parameter an (array of) values. These must be either the users `DistinguishedName`, `ObjectGUID`, `ObjectSID`, `SamAccountName` or a `Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser` object.

You are feeding it the `$user` object from your CSV, which has **none** of these properties.
The way to go there is to capture the result of the `New-ADUser` cmdlet in a variable and use that (or one of the above mentioned properties from that) object for the `-Member` parameter.

Also, I would strongly advise to use Splatting the parameters so you don't have to create those horrible long lines of code where mistakes can be made quite easily.

Try:

```
$userParams = @{
    # you forgot this one
    SamAccountName        = $user.Achternaam
    # and UserPrincipalName must have format: username@domain name (UPN suffix)
    UserPrincipalName     = '{0}@asgard.com' -f $user.Achternaam
    Name                  = '{0} {1}' -f $user.Voornaam, $user.Achternaam
    GivenName             = $user.Voornaam
    Surname               = $user.Achternaam
    AccountPassword       = $password
    ProfilePath           = '\\Thor\UserProfiles\{0}' -f $user.Achternaam
    Path                  = 'OU={0},OU={1},OU=Asgard,DC=Asgard,DC=com' -f $user.Locatie, $user.Afdeling
    Homedrive             = 'D'
    Homedirectory         = '\\Thor\UserData\{0}' -f $user.Achternaam
    OfficePhone           = '+31{0}'-f $user.Telefoon
    Office                = $user.Locatie
    Department            = $user.Afdeling
    Title                 = $user.Functie
    PasswordNeverExpires  = $True
    ChangePasswordAtLogon = $False
    Enabled               = $True
}

$ADUser = New-ADUser @userParams -PassThru  # use PassThru to capture the newly created user
```

Now that you have an ADUser object, you can use that on the Add-ADGroupMember line:

```
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $globalgroup -Members $ADUser
```

P.S. It is also advisable to first check if a user with that SamAccountName already exists in the domain, and if so output a warning and skip that user. For that use:

```
foreach ($user in $users) {
    $ADUSer = Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$($user.Achternaam)'" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($ADUser) {
        Write-Warning "A user '$($user.Achternaam)' already exists in the domain"
        continue  # skip this user and proceed with the next one
    }

    # here the rest of the code
}
```

---

O yes, the reason why `New-ADUser` failed was:

- You didn't specify the (required) SamAccountName
- The UserPrincipalName was syntactically wrong (see inline comment)

Comment: Well, As mentioned in the comment below. 

I've used this script in this format before, specifically with just the UserPrincipalName as specified above and was able to make users and login to them.

So, I'm not really sure if what you're saying is all to valid.

As far as the Add-ADGroupMember goes, I kinda was thinking the same. I will try to pipeline those arguments into it. Thanks for the respond!

Comment: The error was this: I specified the OU in the wrong order. $department should go before $location. It didn't have anything to dot with the SamAccountName or UserPrincipalName.

Comment: @JordivanDeerse Well... Those are definitely **serious** errors, so Active Directory will certainly not agree with you there..

Comment: @JordivanDeerse And as you stayed yourself in the question _The OU's are all made perfectly_, but now you say that is where the problem was. Without SamAccountName **and** with a wrongly created UPN, there is no way the user could have been created.